# getting specific rows in a grouped dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas

i have a pandas dataframe
euc data which consists of columns

```
code1  code2 euclidean_distance
```

I wanted to get top 50 rows for every group of **code1** sorted on **euclidean distance**,
to get this i used:

```
matrix_top_50 = euc_data.sort_values(['code1', 'euclidean_distance'])
.groupby('code1').head(50).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Now i want to create another matrix to get the next 100 rows for every group of **code1** sorted on **euclidean distance**

For that i tried to use **.iloc**

```
start = 51
end = 151
next_matrix = euc_data.sort_values(['code1', 'euclidean_distance'])
.groupby('code1').iloc[start:end].reset_index(drop=True)
```

But i am getting error:

`Cannot access callable attribute 'iloc' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to do it for every group of code1? Do you understand what `groupby` does?

Comment: @AndreyF Yes i want for every group of code1

Comment: @AndreyF i edited by question,Thanks:)

Comment: Some data and expected output would be nice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html), but is necessary data have to contains rows by `start` and `end`, else error:

```
ext_matrix = (euc_data.sort_values(['code1', 'euclidean_distance'])
                      .groupby('code1')
                      .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[start:end])
                      .reset_index(drop=True) 
              )
```

Comment: working,just testing whether if there is any intersection between the two dataframes,  `matrix_top_50 and ext_matrix`

Comment: Super, glad can help!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is a better solution but you can use `apply` as the error hints:

```
next_matrix = euc_data.sort_values(['code1', 'euclidean_distance'])\
    .groupby('code1').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[start:end]).\
    reset_index(drop=True)
```